# How can I access a function with the same name held on multiple different scripts in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working in Unity on a game with a spell casting system where I have a casting manager script that has a game object list of all the equipped spells (called spells and selectedSpell is just an int that determines which spell in the list is selected so I can cycle through them) and then on each game object/spell, I have a script that will do different things based on the spell. Each game object only has the one script, a sprite renderer, and a transform. The issue I'm having is here:

```
//Cast manager Script
if (Input.GetKeyUp("c"))
            {
                Debug.Log($"Cast {spells[selectedSpell]}");
                spells[selectedSpell].GetComponent<FireballSpell>().Cast();
            }
```

The Cast function contained in the script I'm trying to access looks like this:

```
///Water spell named "WaterSpell"
    public void Cast()
    {
        Debug.Log("Sploosh");
    }
```

```
    //FireballSpell
    public void Cast()
    {
        Debug.Log("Kabloom");
    }
```

I threw in a script for now (the "FireballSpell") and it accesses Cast() just fine when I've got the fireball spell selected, however I'm not sure how to access Cast() from my "WaterSpell" for example. I tried doing `GetComponent(nameof($"{spells[selectedSpell]}")).Cast()` because I've been giving the scripts the same name as the game object, but I just get an error saying, "component does not contain a definition for cast". I'm not really sure how to proceed with this aside from making a bunch of "if selected spell is named x look for this script" for each spell but while it would work, I feel like it could be much more efficient and I don't want to have to worry about adding to the casting manager script if I decide to add more spells down the line.

[image: An image of the fireball game object to show that the script and the game object have the same name]

Thanks in advance to anyone who stumbles on this. If more information is needed I'll try to provide it.

Comment: This is why interfaces were made. So ISpell has a Cast method and you just call the variable ISpell myspell=getcomponent<fireball> …. my spell.Cast(). Typed on a phone battling autocorrect. Sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a little bit of research since I'm still a bit of a newbie but BugFinder's suggestion of using Interfaces worked. In case anyone finds this and needs it, I created a new script that was just an interface called ISpell that had the Cast method in it and then I made it so my spells could use the ISpell interface. In my casting manager I changed

```
spells[selectedSpell].GetComponent<FireballSpell>().Cast();
```

to

```
var Spell = spells[selectedSpell].GetComponent<ISpell>();
```

and then I just had to add `Spell.Cast();`
Thank you BugFixer and also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LA3BLqOw9g)